# How to transform first row as column name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I hope you are all well.
I would like your help on a data transformation task that I have.
I would like to convert the first row of a table to a column name

I am working on SQL Server Azure and I get daily data from another service.

This service loads a table that is of the same form.

[image]

and I would like to transform the data in the same manner

[image]

Do You have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: How big are your tables? How many records?

Comment: Hello. Table have about 500 rows

Comment: You could use temp tables. You do not specify is the number of columns always the same.?

Comment: The number of columns regularly change and the name of columns change too.

Comment: So, the temporary table should be created dynamically. Does the pattern is always the same? Does it mean the column names, as well as values, are always separated by ";" ( semicolumn)?

Comment: [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) seems to work in Azure...

Comment: Yes. The pattern is Always the same. separated is always a semicolumn.

Comment: What's the data format you get from another service, csv files? Which tool did you use to import this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this is by using a little dynamic SQL magic:

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us thus step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T As Table
(
    Row_num int,
    Line nvarchar(4000)
);

INSERT INTO @T (Row_Num, Line) VALUES
(1, 'Col1;Col2;Col3'),
(2, 'Val1;Val2;Val3'),
(3, 'Value1;Value2;Value1'),
(4, 'Val A; val B;Val A'),
(5, 'Value A; Value B;Value C');
```

Then, build a union all query that selects the values from every row but the first, replacing the semicolon (`;`) separator with a comma (`,`) surrounded by apostrophes (`'`). Add an apostrophe before and after the string (which means we are treating all the data as strings):

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @Sql += 'UNION ALL SELECT '''+ REPLACE(Line, ';', ''',''') + ''' '
FROM @T 
WHERE Row_Num > 1;
```

Next, use `stuff` to replace the first `UNION ALL` with a common table expression declaration, specifying the column names in the declaration itself. Note that here we don't need the apostrophes anymore, just to replace the semicolon with a comma:

```
SELECT @Sql = STUFF(@Sql, 1, 10, 'WITH CTE('+ REPLACE(Line, ';', ',') +') AS (') + ') SELECT * FROM CTE'
FROM @T 
WHERE Row_Num = 1;
```

Finally, execute the sql:

```
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Results:

```
Col1        Col2        Col3
Val1        Val2        Val3
Value1      Value2      Value1
Val A        val B      Val A
Value A      Value B    Value C
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/WHSGL9422)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to transform your text data into valid `JSON` arrays and then use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with an explicit schema and dynamic statement.

**Working example:**

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   RowNum int,
   Line nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (RowNum, Line)
VALUES
   (1, 'ColumnA;ColumnB;ColumnC'),
   (2, 'ValueA1;ValueB1;ValueC1'),
   (3, 'ValueA2;ValueB2;ValueC2'),
   (4, 'ValueA3;ValueB3;ValueC3'),
   (5, 'ValueA4;ValueB4;ValueC4'),
   (6, 'ValueA5;ValueB5;ValueC5')
```

T-SQL:

```
-- Explicit schema generation
DECLARE @schema nvarchar(max)
SELECT @schema = STUFF((
   SELECT CONCAT(N',', j.[value], N' nvarchar(max) ''$[', j.[key], N']''')
   FROM #Data d
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(d.Line, ';', '","'), N'"]')) j
   WHERE d.RowNum = 1
   FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, N'')

-- Dymanic statement
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = CONCAT(
   N'SELECT j.* FROM #Data d ',
   N'CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N''[["'', REPLACE(d.Line, '';'', ''","''), N''"]]'')) ',
   N'WITH (',
   @schema,
   N') j WHERE d.RowNum > 1'
)

-- Execution
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Output:

```
-----------------------
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
-----------------------
ValueA1 ValueB1 ValueC1
ValueA2 ValueB2 ValueC2
ValueA3 ValueB3 ValueC3
ValueA4 ValueB4 ValueC4
ValueA5 ValueB5 ValueC5
```

**Explanations:**

The main part is to transform each row's data into valid `JSON` arrays. The count of the columns can be different.

Data from the first row will be used for explicit schema generation and values `ColumnA;ColumnB;ColumnC` are transformed into `["ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnC"]`. Values from subsequent rows `ValueA1;ValueB1;ValueC1` are transformed into `[["ValueA1","ValueB1","ValueC1"]]`.

Next simple examples demonstrate how `OPENJSON()` returns data with default and explicit schema:

With default schema:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = '["ValueA1", "ValueB1", "ValueC1"]'
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

Output for default schema:

```
----------------
key value   type
----------------
0   ValueA1 1
1   ValueB1 1
2   ValueC1 1
```

With explicit schema:

```
SET @json = '[["ValueA1", "ValueB1", "ValueC1"]]'
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (
   ColumnA nvarchar(max) '$[0]',
   ColumnB nvarchar(max) '$[1]',
   ColumnC nvarchar(max) '$[2]'
)
```

Output for explicit schema:

```
-----------------------
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
-----------------------
ValueA1 ValueB1 ValueC1
```